# Question on Portfolio Risk & Covariance

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation, covariance, risk

Good evening,

I was reading a stats textbook where I came across the following statement:

> In order to reduce the portfolio risk of a portfolio involving two risky investments, we should choose their covariance to be negative, rather than positive

I don't really get what it means. From what I understand:

> Cov = 0, the variables are not related
>
> Cov = 0 to 1, the if the value of one variable increases, so will the other
>
> Cov = -1 to 0, the if the value of one variable increases, the other will decrease

Am I right to then say that why having a negative covariance will reduce risk is because when one investment falls, the other will react to counter? So in such cases, the profits will be always minimal but safe.

In contrast, if the investments are positively correlated, then the portfolio will be highly risky, but highly profitable if one makes a profit.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}$
$\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}$
$\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$
 Consider a portfolio, $P_{i} = w_{i1}*X_{i} + w_{i2}*Y_{i}$. For a given expected return, $\E[P_i] = \E[X_i] + \E[Y_i]$, we want to construct the portfolio in a manner which minimizes the overall volatility (risk), which is typically measured in terms of standard deviation. Equivalently, we can use the variance as a measurement of risk, since it is just volatility squared. Then, the overall variance of our portfolio is:
$$
\Var[P_i] = w_{i1}^{2}*\Var[X_i] + w_{i2}^{2}*\Var[Y_i] + 2*\Cov[X_{i},Y_{i}]*w_{i1}*w_{i2}
$$
So, for a given expected return, we choose a combination of assets $X_{i}$ and $Y_{i}$ which minimizes $\Var[P_{i}]$, i.e. $\Cov[X_{i},Y_{i}] < 0$.